# Error producing PDF417 barcode in POS .NET

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-printing

So as the title suggests I cannot print PDF417 with POS .NET. I have a TSP 100 ECO by Star Micronics. I have resorted to using my printers SDK to print the barcode but it is so buggy I ***really*** want to get it working with POS .NET.

With the SDK code I am sending bytes code to the printer whereas, with POS .NET I have tried multiple things but most recently something like so:

```
p.PrintBarCode(PrinterStation.Receipt, "123", BarCodeSymbology.PDF417, barCodeHeight, (p.RecLineWidth / 2), PosPrinter.PrinterBarCodeCenter, BarCodeTextPosition.Below);
```

However, this does not work... when I send commands with byte code from the SDK I am specifying, the security level, ratio etc as so:

```
//Get all the user settings for PDF 417 barcode printing
string PDFsizeCmd = string.Empty;
//size
string height = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(2);
string width = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(7);
//security level
string ecc = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(5);
//x dimension
string xdim = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(4);
//x to y size ratio
string ratio = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(1);
//length of data
string strLen = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(data.Length);

PDFsizeCmd = "\x1b\x1d\x78\x53\x30\x00" + height + width;
string PDFeccCmd = "\x1b\x1d\x78\x53\x31" + ecc;
string PDFxdimCmd = "\x1b\x1d\x78\x53\x32" + xdim;
string PDFratioCmd = "\x1b\x1d\x78\x53\x33" + ratio;
string PDFdataCmd = "\x1b\x1d\x78\x44" + strLen + "\x00" + data + "\x0a";
string PDFprintCmd = "\x1b\x1d\x78\x50";
print2DBarcode(PDFsizeCmd + PDFeccCmd + PDFxdimCmd + PDFratioCmd + PDFdataCmd + PDFprintCmd);
```

With microsoft POS there are not commands like so, which has made me believe that is the case of it not working.. I have scoured google/PDF's etc for information but it is very limited and I have not found any examples of printing a 2D PDF417 barcode online. If anyone code point me in the right direction or share your knowledge , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to play with the the physical size of the barcode (trying to incrase it by x2 or more to see if it works): it could that the given physical size can not be enough for the data and the security level you use for PDF417 barcode using the printer's resolution.